# (Almost) linearely separable dataset, where can I find one?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, perceptron

I'm implementing the perceptron algorithm and the voted perceptron algorithm for an assignment for university.
For that I need to find some decent datasets.. I've tried the UCI repos and I've come up with:

- The banknote authentication dataset:
  https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/banknote+authentication
- Occupancy dataset: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Occupancy+Detection+

that work quite nicely, the accuracy is pretty high for the linear separability.
HOWEVER I need to find a third dataset to end my assignment, I've been searching everywhere but I can't seem to find anymore of them, the dataset has to have more than 1000 examples, and it has to be binary classifiable obviously..

**Does anyone of you know where I could find such a dataset?**

I've been trying the Adult dataset, but it's pretty much sparse.. far from being linearly separable..

NOTE: I can't use the kernel trick or any other higher dimensional paradigm.

Comment: There is a similar question on 
 https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/247057/linearly-separable-data-set and in one of the answers they points taht there is a Iris Dataset with some of the classes been linearly separable

Comment: Also this [reddit question](https://www.reddit.com/r/datasets/comments/1o9w87/wanted_linearly_separable_dataset_for_ann_training/) has a nice proposal for this kind of problem
 > "If you're just playing with data, another approach would be to find the separation that best separates a set of data, then remove the points or dimensions that violate the linear separation. It wouldn't be valid for publication, but it could still be useful for practicing your ANN work."

Comment: This question is likely a better fit at [Opendata.SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Could you use a synthetic data set? It should be very easy to generate your own dataset that is "almost linearly separable".